# Beacons name changed - how clear BT name cache

Tags: ibeacon, android-bluetooth, altbeacon

In my app I am using beacons name for work. After name change of beacons, some are seeing OK, some not. They show old name. I find that there's problem with bluetooth cache in device. How can I clear cache? 
I tried:

```
public void btDevice(){
    BluetoothDevice device = mbluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(idKey);
    device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
```

But not success. 
I wish to avoid use android.bluetooth because I wish to avoid prompting for pairing every time device is in range. Now I use altbeacon lib to manage beacons.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, the bluetooth name is parsed from the scan response by the operating system.  You have very little control over how this works -- the last Bluetooth LE scan response detected for a device is associated with Android's object for a device with the same mac address.  If the device name changes at a later time, Android will continue reporting the old name unless a new scan response is received by the OS.  It is the OS that decides when to request a new scan response, not the application code.

As you have seen, none of this is under your control and it is not guaranteed.  I don't know of any workarounds on this, and avoid using scan responses for data (like the bluetooth name) that may change over time.

Comment: I need bt name it's easier and more flexible(in my app) than using minor/major numbers. Beacon name is address html element. I clean bluetooth data in Settings/applications but this doesn't help. This problem is pain in the ...  only for me, because i setup my beacons with the same device and when i testing my app i see old names and app crashes. User will connect first time and get proper name. But now i have problem with building my app.